# Facebook login approved but can't be used

Tags: facebook, facebook-login, facebook-apps

The following sections of my Facebook app is approved:

- app details
- email
- public_profile
- user_friends

but still I see the following message when trying to login with users:

"App Not Setup: This app is still in development mode, and you don't have access to it. Switch to a registered test user or ask an app admin for permissions."

Why is it happening? What am I forgetting?

Answer (score 0):

You have to make your app public. Go to https://developers.facebook.com/apps/ and select your app, then go to "Status & Review" and set the button on the upper right side (*Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public?*) to **Yes**...

That should do.